# How to add a "delete" action in the search results

Tags: salesforce1-app, administration, isv

When searching for custom objects using SalesForce 'search' at the top of the page we get the search results with an option to edit each record.

Is it possible to customize the search results layout and add a 'Delete' option near the 'Edit' option

Image attached

[image]

Comment: What does this question have to do with the salesforce1 app?

Comment: This relating to our app as an ISV partner

Answer (score 2):

If you (your user profile) does not have permission to delete the record. 'Delete' option would not show up in the action column.

Comment: I have all permissions including Delete